# Maven build issue; not all mentioned plugins appear in target folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins

Below is a sample from my pom.xml. In all, there are 3 user defined plugins but I think the issue comes from one of the below plugins.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}/X</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>../X/src</directory>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>../X/src</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>util/App.js</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/Config</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>../ConfigUI/src</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Order of plugins on pom =  **Plugin A, Plugin X and Plugin Config**

The issue is when I do a maven install (in eclipse), it only copies the resources for Plugin A and Plugin X.

Now if I alter the order of plugins to **Plugin A, Plugin Config and Plugin X**, maven install copies resources of "**X**" plugin and **Config** is skipped somehow. What could be the issue?

Comment: Why not merge plugin executions, and have a single plugin with 3 executions instead?

Comment: Merging plugin executions did i wanted but still not convinced if this is advisable given the scenario. Also, i still need to understand what's the issue with ordering of plugins.

Comment: Why do you need to manually copy things into the target directory. I would suggest to use frontend-maven-plugin or similar to handle that...

Comment: I do not manually do it. Maven build does.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit unclear what are the pieces that you refer to as "plugin A", "plugin X" and "plugin Config", I'm going to assume that they are individual `resource` sections in your example above.

Therefore, have a look at this snippet:

```
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../X/src</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../X/src</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>util/App.js</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
```

It seems that because of the second `resource` tag, some of your file will get overwritten (notice the fact that they both refer to the same `../X/src` directory as source. Some overwriting is bound to happen.

Comment: Plugin A is one plugin section for a single resource which i have not included in the snippet.

Plugin X is one having "X" in directory tag and similarly plugin Config.

These 3 are different resources with different directories to copy the source from. Moreover, as I mentioned about the order of plugins, the plugin at 2nd place out of these 3, does not gets copied to target so I think its not because of 2nd resource tag.